# Testing WCF service on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment, azure

I created a WCF service in Windows Azure project (with 1 WCF Service Web Role).

How can I test it at my local machine? If I want to write an application, which makes a request to this service, what reference in the application should I add?

When I press F5 in this project, it shows me a web page in browser, where it is written "HTTP error 403.14 - Forbidden".

Sorry for such a silly question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Azure project as the start up project.  This will start the azure emulator which will host your wcf service on localhost.  I believe it automatically opens a browser with your site loaded.  If not, you can always check out the emulator itself in your system tray to get the ports (very similar to the way you would with development server).  Of course you must be on the correct path to your service as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a service reference to your test project with the uri for the service exposed on Azure

Comment: I understand this, but where can I get this service reference? Where it is written? How to get the link, if the service is hosted on the local machine?

Comment: You said you are hosting the service in Azure...?

Comment: I have a Visual Studio Windows Azure Project, in which a WCF service is implemented. I launch it with F5, but I don't see how to get the link to this service in order to use it in another application (client app).